# Linux Command to get fully qualified name of each class in directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a file directory structure as follows:

```
src \
    SortGreater \
           SortGreater.java
           SortGreater.class
    SortLess \
           SortLess.java
           SortLess.class
```

I intend to write a Linux command that outputs the fully qualified name of each class in a "src" directory (given that I am running the command in the "src" directory). For example, the command should output "SortGreater.SortGreater" and "SortLess.SortLess" here. My first attempt at this was the command `find -type f -name "*.java" -exec readlink -f {} \;` but this proved to be wrong as it output `/path/to/directory/src/SortGreater/SortGreater.java` and `/path/to/directory/src/SortLess/SortLess.java`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your desired output (no description) for that sample input.

Comment: `cd /path/to/directorry/src ; find ... | sed 's#somethingHere#somethingDifferentHere#g` Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Find all `.class` (or `.java`) files, change slashes to dots, trim:

```
find -name '*.class' | sed 's~/~.~g; s/.class$//; s/..//'
```

Comment: I suggest to replace `...` with `..`. I assume that you want to remove only the first two characters.

Answer (score 2):

Let's use the `-exec` option of `find` with a `bash` function (`to_qual`) that takes a parameter, removes the trailing `.java` and the leading `./`, replaces all `/` with `.`, and prints the result.

```
$ cd src
$ to_qual() { f="${1%.*}"; f="${f#./}"; printf "%s\n" "${f////.}"; }
$ export -f to_qual
$ find -type f -name '*.java' -exec bash -c 'to_qual "$1"' _ {} \;
SortGreater.SortGreater
SortLess.SortLess
```

Comment: very nice use of `bash` functions here. More people need to be aware of this option for executing multiple operations on the output from find. Good luck to all!